# Chrome Browser: Adding Options to a Select Box doesn't show in dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

When a user clicks on a selectbox, an Ajax even occurs.

This event places options in to the select box.

After the options are placed in to the select box the user should be able to click on them.

In Chrome, when you click the drop down list appears "Select One" but after the options are added, the list still is "Select One"  the user can hit the down arrow key and select it, but it is not shown in the "drop down list of options" after they are added.

What magical piece of JS or jQuery would refresh this drop down list being displayed without a second click in chrome?

When the option is clicked this is being executed via JS:

```
secBox = document.getElementById('sel34541_75');
secBox.length = 1;
addOption(secBox, "Option 1", "execPopDrop('sel34541_75', 34541, 'Option 1', 'type1', 'page.php')");
addOption(secBox, "Option 2", "execPopDrop('sel34541_75', 34541, 'Option 2', 'type2', 'page.php')");
addOption(secBox, "Option 3", "execPopDrop('sel34541_75', 34541, 'Option 3', 'type3', 'page.php')");
addOption(secBox, "Option 4", "execPopDrop('sel34541_75', 34541, 'Option 4', 'type4', 'page.php')");
```

Add option function looks like this:

```
function addOption(selectbox, text, value) {
  selectbox.options[selectbox.options.length]=new Option(text,value);
}
```

If i click and then hit the down arrow, I see the dynamic options are there, but not in the list visible. (again this works in IE and FF)

[image: If i hit the down arrow, I see the dynamic options]

If I click it a second time I see the correct options in the drop down

[image: If I click it a second time I see the correct options in the drop down]

Comment: The short answer to this ended up being, don't bother! Doing it onFocus, onHover, onClick etc was a waste of time. Instead I went with a more elegant solution and made a "Context Menu" work on right and left click after clicking on a span.  Less code, less room for error, and more compatibility!

Answer (score 0):

Try this - works in all browsers - if you need support for IE4, then you need to add 1 to the options.length before adding the option ;)

**update** this solution is to the original question

```
function addOption(selectbox, text, value) {
  selectbox.options[selectbox.options.length]=new Option(text,value);
}
```

However WHY add that horrible string to the option?

Looks like you would (shudder) EVAL the string in the value

Why not

```
addOption(secBox, "Option 1", "sel34541_75");
```

and then in execPopDrop pass the select, then it would be

```
function execPopDrop(sel) {
  var val = sel[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  var txt = sel[sel.selectedIndex].text;
  var type="type"+val.split(" ")[1]; // from Option 1
  var parm2 = val.replace(/[sel_]/g,""); // 34541
  // here you have all the stuff you need to do whatever you did before
}
```

Comment: Let's stick to the first problem first if we could and I will evaluate the second portion at a later time.  I have updated my code for the "addOption" function.  It still works the same.  I have cleared Cache.  I also updated the original post to show CHROME's downfall.  We need some sort of work around for it.

Comment: Show me how and where you call the function to add. I re-read your question and I must say I do not like the idea of populating something like a select on click of that select. Perhaps on focus, or trigger click again after the Ajax is finished

Comment: Actually you might just need to replace the select completely and add the complete select again to the parent container using innerHTML

Comment: I like the idea of adding a blank select, then on-click, re-populate the container holding the select box, and then a click trigger.

OnFocus may work too...  Let me investigate. I will come back in a few hours.

Comment: Never could get this to work, went with a different solution. a jQuery context menu that was also bound to the click event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060811/jquery-make-left-invoke-right-click-context-menu